# checkbox checked if value is 1

Tags: php

why this is not working?
I want this check the checkbox if `pro_cat` variable is greater than or equal one else unchecked the checkbox

```php
<?php
  $checked="";
  if($pro_cat>=1){
    $checked="checked";
  }

  echo"
    <tr>        
       <td ><br>Day<hr>Night</td>
       <td>
         <label class='container'>
           <input type='checkbox' checked='$checked'>
           <span class='checkmark'></span>
         </label>";

?>
```

Comment: what HTML does this part produce? Did you check what PHP send back to the browser (view source)? I think you will find a hint there.

Comment: Replace `checked='$checked'` with just `$checked`

Comment: The fact that you have the word `checked` at all makes it checked. `checked='off'` or `='no'` or `=0` will still be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition on false becomes like this: `<input type='checkbox' checked=''>` which is always true for making checked to checkbox. So change like this:

```
<?php
$checked="";
        if($pro_cat>=1){

            $checked="checked";
        }

        echo"
        <tr>        

                    <td ><br>Day<hr>Night</td>
                    <td>
                    <label class='container'>
                        <input type='checkbox' $checked>
                        <span class='checkmark'></span>
                    </label>";

?>
```